# How to make nice camera shutter animation on Android

Tags: android, animation, camera

I want a nice camera shutter effect for my camera overlay in Android.

How can I do this?

The following is my attempt, any other [fancier](http://dl.xda-developers.com/attachdl/926176e77c1341a6b3bce5cf5c1de5ae/517bd0cd/1/7/5/6/7/7/7/download.jpg) effect like in iOS?

[image: This is what I've done]

Comment: Google on acrivity change animation, maby is that what you are looking for

Comment: @MaikelBollemeijer Thanks for the suggestion :) But I do know how to change the animation of activity. Just that I wanted a fancier animation to open up a camera.

Comment: @Roylee how did you manage to show the camera preview in portrait mode, including QR code scanning? i thought that such a thing causes weird results on both the preview and the output image.

Comment: @androiddeveloper that was my intention to tweak it into portrait mode as I would like the camera preview to remain under its parent. Just like what you have seen, with actionbar on top.

Comment: @Roylee yes, but how did you do it? does it work well? according to my experience, setting the camera preview to run on portrait mode causes weird problems on many devices. usually people would simply suggest that i use the "natural" orientation of the camera which is landscape for this issue.

Comment: @androiddeveloper Yes It works very well, on other devices as well, just some minor tweaking on the zXing library. :) And my app is purely to scan QR code.

Comment: @Roylee can you please post about it somewhere? last time i've tried it , it was really terrible and messy and in the end i've just used landscape and rotated everything, so the user thinks it's portrait, but it's in fact landscape.

Comment: @androiddeveloper Okay I have made the post for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16252791/how-to-show-zxing-camera-in-potrait-mode/16252917#16252917

Comment: @Roylee thanks! i think you can also gain some credit for answering this question that was asked by others. i'm sure this question exists somewhere : http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=zxing+portrait